# How to separate non identical entries from two columns of excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns in a excel sheet as shown below.

```
Column A    Column B
87            87
107           107
108           108
117           117
119           119
153           153
170           170
174           174
209           209
409106386989  409014007285
409110099164  174
```

Here both columns A and B contains 11 entries.
Now I have to find out the non identical entries from both columns.
i.e entries 409106386989 and 409110099164 are present only in Column A but not in B.
So I have to separate these entries from Column A.

Like wise entries 409014007285 present only in column B but not in A.
Also there are two entries 174 in column B but only one entry in column A.
So I have to separate these two entries i.e 409014007285  and 174 from column B.

So the Output should be as below.

```
    Column A               Column B       A but not B        B but not A
          87                     87      409106386989                174
         107                    107      409110099164       409014007285
         108                    108
         117                    117
         119                    119
         153                    153
         170                    170
         174                    174
         209                    209
409106386989           409014007285
409110099164                    174
```

I am doing this process manually which is taking much time when the entries are thousand togather.

Is it possible to do this by running some code (Using V B scripting)...?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The question was terribly formatted (well done to @DevonParsons for a good edit) and reads like you've made no effort.

Comment: Additionally, are the pairs formatted as pairs or would that need to be done as well? We can't help you solve a specific problem unless you have a specific problem with the methods you've already tried. Perhaps give us some background on why you're stuck.

Comment: [Structured references in Excel Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-formulas-in-excel-tables-HA102749547.aspx) & the programming language [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) comes with an excel.au3 library.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub GetUnique()
    Dim N As Long, M As Long, i As Long, K As Long, L As Long
    Dim r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    K = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        Set r = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(M, 2)).Find(v)
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Cells(K, "C").Value = v
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i

    K = 1
    For i = 1 To M
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(N, 1)).Find(v)
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Cells(K, "D").Value = v
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

This macro processes data in columns **A** & **B.**  The output data is placed in columns **C** & **D.**

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#2**

This macro, similar to the first, will handle multiple occurrences of the same value in both columns **A** & **B**

```
Sub FindNonDuplicates()
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("C1")
    Range("B:B").Copy Range("D1")
    Dim nC As Long, nD As Long, v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    nC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    nD = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = nC To 1 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "C").Value
        For j = 1 To nD
            If v = Cells(j, "D").Value Then
                Cells(i, "C").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Cells(j, "D").Delete Shift:=xlUp
                nD = nD - 1
                GoTo qwerty
            End If
        Next j
qwerty:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does this code do? How does it work? How would one execute it and/or modify it if they had a different structure? Expanding on what the code does makes it more useful for someone who isn't well-versed with VBA.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thank you for your comments!  I will **EDIT** the answer to supply more information

Comment: @DaveRook You are correct!! I will look into fixing this bug!